# REST Jersey Client - unable to parse JSON into POJO class

Tags: java, json, rest, maven, jersey-2.0

I am trying to build a rest client using jersey 2.13.

The rest endpoint is in : https://gist.githubusercontent.com/richersoon/ff4dd5c5abe414c5ec4c/raw/4ce49c32e57bf071d052f7efa76f332d60308035/user.json

But when I tried to run the application I got:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MessageBodyProviderNotFoundException: MessageBodyReader not found for media type=text/plain, type=class com.napier.entity.User, genericType=class com.napier.entity.User.
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderInterceptorExecutor$TerminalReaderInterceptor.aroundReadFrom(ReaderInterceptorExecutor.java:173)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderInterceptorExecutor.proceed(ReaderInterceptorExecutor.java:134)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MessageBodyFactory.readFrom(MessageBodyFactory.java:988)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.InboundMessageContext.readEntity(InboundMessageContext.java:833)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.InboundMessageContext.readEntity(InboundMessageContext.java:768)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.InboundJaxrsResponse.readEntity(InboundJaxrsResponse.java:96)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ScopedJaxrsResponse.access$001(ScopedJaxrsResponse.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ScopedJaxrsResponse$1.call(ScopedJaxrsResponse.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:228)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:397)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ScopedJaxrsResponse.readEntity(ScopedJaxrsResponse.java:74)
    at com.napier.service.rest.UsersClient.main(UsersClient.java:20)
```

Here's the code:

```
public class UsersClient {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
        WebTarget target = client.target(
                UriBuilder.fromUri(
                        "https://gist.githubusercontent.com/richersoon/ff4dd5c5abe414c5ec4c/raw/4ce49c32e57bf071d052f7efa76f332d60308035/user.json"));

        Response response = target.request().accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).get(Response.class);
        User user = response.readEntity(User.class);
        System.out.println(user);
    }
}
```

Here's the POJO:

```
@XmlRootElement
public class User {

    private String firstname;
    private String lastname;
    private String photourl;

    ... setters and getters...
}
```

Here's the POM:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
    <version>2.13</version>
</dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-moxy</artifactId>
        <version>2.13</version>
    </dependency>
```

Please guide me because I am totally new to webservices.

Answer (score 0):

Your client is accepting results of media type "application/json", but your REST webservice returns "text/plain". Check this post to see a possible solution: [MessageBodyReader not found for media type=application/octet-stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19846577/messagebodyreader-not-found-for-media-type-application-octet-stream)

Answer (score 0):

Seems you are trying to access the wring uri, which is plain text.

I was able to get it to work with this uri, which is the actual .json file

```
"https://gist.github.com/richersoon/ff4dd5c5abe414c5ec4c#file-user-json"
```